# Perl script connect issues (Snap Surveys)

Tags: perl, email, smtp

I am currently running this script on my host and attempting to connect to my own SMTP server to send the results of the survey after it is submitted.

However, I am receiving a 500 Internal Server Error when running this Perl script. The script is located on GoDaddy servers and attempting to connect to my mail server.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#First released with snap 10

$port = 25; #SMTP PORT NUMBER
$smtpServer = 'SMTP_SERVER';
$domain = 'DOMAIN';
$sWebMaster='WEBMASTER';
$sReturnURL='http://alliancesurveys.org';
$sReturnText='Back to surveys';

use Socket;
use URI::Escape;

$SIG{'INT'} = 'dokill';
sub dokill {
    kill 9,$child if $child;
}

($name,$aliases,$proto) = getprotobyname('tcp');
($name,$aliases,$port) = getservbyname($port,'tcp')
    unless $port =~ /^\d+$/;;
($name,$aliases,$type,$len,$thataddr) = gethostbyname($smtpServer); #get host records from server

my $iaddr = inet_aton($smtpServer);  
$that = sockaddr_in($port, $iaddr);

read(STDIN , $buffer , $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'}); 
@pairs = split(/&/ , $buffer); 
foreach $pair (@pairs)
{
    ($name,  $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
    $value =~ tr/+/ /;              #Translate + to <space>
    $value =~ s/%0D/ /g;
    $value =~ s/%0A/ /g;
    $value =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;    #Convert Hex values
    $value =~ s/~!/ ~!/g;
    $name =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg; #Do the same for the names
    $name =~ s/~!/ ~!/g;
    $FORM{$name} .= ';' if (defined($FORM{$name})); #Seperate multi values with ;
    $FORM{$name} .= $value;             #Add the value to the control name key
}

if($FORM{':COOKIE:'})
{
    if($ENV{'HTTP_COOKIE'} =~ /\QSURVEY=$FORM{':SURVEY:'}/)   {
        print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
            print "\n\n";
        print "<HTML>\n";
        print "<HEAD><TITLE>Data Received</TITLE></HEAD>\n";
            print "<BODY BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">\n";
        print "<FONT FACE=ARIAL>\n";
            print "<CENTER><H2>Repeat Submission</H2>\n";
            print "<P>You have already submitted data to this survey.Only one submission is allowed.\n";
        print "<P><a href=\"$sReturnURL\">$sReturnText</a>\n";
        print "</CENTER>\n";
        print "</FONT></BODY></HTML>\n";
            exit;
    }
}
$recipient = $FORM{':EMAIL:'};              #Get address from hidden Email control
#Check for malicous use of recipient
if ($recipient =~ />|<|;|\\|\// ) {
#Change this message to change the page returned when the email address cannot be used
    print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
    print "\n\n";
        print "<HEAD><TITLE>Invalid Email Address</TITLE></HEAD>\n";
        print "<BODY BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">\n";
        print "<CENTER><H2>The system is unable to process the</H2><BR><BR>\n";
    print "<CENTER><H2>email address in this form.</H2><BR><BR>\n";
        print "Please report this error to $sWebMaster.</center>\n";
        print "</BODY>\n";
        exit;
}

if($FORM{':RECEIPT:'})
{
    $theQ = $FORM{':RECEIPT:'};
    $sender = $FORM{$theQ};             #Get address from hidden Email control
    #Check for malicous use of sender email
    if(length($sender)==0)
    {
        print "\n\n";
            #print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
            print "<HEAD><TITLE>No Email Address</TITLE></HEAD>\n";
            print "<BODY BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\" TEXT=\"#000000\" LINK=\"#0000ff\" VLINK=\"0000ff\">\n";
        if($FORM{':RECEIPTLBL:'})
        {
            print "<CENTER><H2>You have not given a contact email in $FORM{':RECEIPTLBL:'}.</H2><BR><BR>\n";
        }
        else
        {
                print "<CENTER><H2>You have not given a contact email.</H2><BR><BR>\n";
        }
        print "<CENTER><H2>The address must be given so a receipt can be sent</H2><BR><BR>\n";
            print "Please use the back button on your browser to return to the questionnaire and enter an address.</center>\n";
            print "</BODY>\n";
            exit;
    }
}

if (!socket(S, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, $proto)) {
    die $!;
}

if (!connect(S,$that)) {
    die $!;
}

select (S);
$|=1;               # flush
select (STDOUT);
$|=1;               # flush

#set up ESMTP session here
$stat = <S>;
die("500 fatal: bad message on connect: $stat") if ($stat !~ /^2/);
print S "HELO $domain\r\n";
$stat = <S>;
die("500 fatal: bad message on HELO: $stat") if ($stat !~ /^2/);
print S "MAIL FROM:<surveyScript\@$domain>\r\n";
$stat = <S>;
die("500 fatal: bad message on MAIL FROM: $stat") if ($stat !~ /^2/);
print S "RCPT TO:<$FORM{':EMAIL:'}>";
print S "\r\n";
$stat = <S>;
die("500 fatal: bad message on RCPT TO: $stat") if ($stat !~ /^2/);
print S "DATA\r\n";
$stat= <S>;
print S "To: $FORM{':EMAIL:'} \n";

print S"Subject: Internet submission of $FORM{':SURVEY:'} data\n\n";

print S "***START SURVEY DATA***\n";
my $doEscape = $FORM{':MSGENCODE:'} ? 1 : 0;
if ($doEscape)
{
    $FORM{':MSGENCODE:'} = "2";
}
foreach $key (keys(%FORM))
{
    if ($key !~ /^:OKPAGE:$/)
    {
        my $val = $FORM{$key};
        if ($doEscape)
        {
            $val = uri_escape($val, "^A-Za-z0-9\-_.!~*'()\x20@");
        }
        print S "$key=$val\n";
    }
}
print S "***END SURVEY DATA***\n";
print S "\r\n.\r\n";
$stat= <S>;
die("500 fatal: bad message on DATA END: $stat") if ($stat !~ /^2/);
print S "QUIT\r\n";
#close socket here
close(S);

if($FORM{':COOKIE:'})
{
    print "Set-Cookie: SURVEY=$FORM{':SURVEY:'} ; expires=$FORM{':COOKIE:'}\n";
}
if($FORM{':OKPAGE:'})
{
    print "Location: $FORM{':OKPAGE:'}\n\n";
}else{
    print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
    print "<HEAD><TITLE>Thank-you</TITLE></HEAD>\n";
    print "<BODY BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">\n";
    print "<center>\n";
    print "<h2>Thank You</h2>\n";
    print "Thank you for taking the time to answer this survey.<p>\n";
    print "Your response has been submitted succesfully to $FORM{':EMAIL:'}.<p>\n";
    print "<a href=\"$sReturnURL\">$sReturnText</a></center>\n";
    print "</body>\n";
}
```

The error log shows "AH01215: Connection refused at Subques.pl" and refers to this line:

```
if (!connect(S,$that)) {
    die $!;
}
```

As far as I can tell, my SMTP server and port are accessible, it just refuses the connection. What might be the problem? Do I somehow need to authenticate while making the connection? I'm assuming (and could be wrong) that it could be an issue with my server. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: *Always* `use strict; use warnings;`!

Comment: Also: 3 arg lexical opens are much safer.

Comment: This is a really old way to send email. Have you looked at [Email::Sender](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Email-Sender/lib/Email/Sender/Manual/QuickStart.pm)?

Comment: I appreciate the recommendations. Unfortunately, this script was provided by the folks at Snap Surveys. It is supposed to be as simple as changing the variable info, uploading to the host, and referencing it. My main issue is the refused connection to the SMTP server. I have contacted them but they do not offer any support other than pointing me to here: [http://www.snapsurveys.com/help/#19519](http://www.snapsurveys.com/help/#19519)

Comment: If someone gave me that Perl code to install and run, that would be a huge red flag for me. How much do you want to deal with these people? I'd be looking for alternative providers.

Comment: Have you verified that your SMTP server is accessible from the host? It is possible that outgoing connections to port 25 have been disallowed. You verify it by trying this on the host: nc -vvv YOUR_SMTP_SERVER 25

Comment: It turns out that GoDaddy disallows the use of Sockets: [https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/20/does-your-cgi-service-support-socket-connections-or-socket-modules](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/20/does-your-cgi-service-support-socket-connections-or-socket-modules). I had to modify the script to use the newer Email::Sender instead. I'm waiting on a reply from GoDaddy in regards to the Simple.pm Perl module because for some reason my script is unable to locate it on their end.